# Why do dbg! and println!("{:?}") show different outputs?

Tags: rust

I had thought that `dbg!(x)` and `println!("{:?}", x)` would both print the same string, since `{:?}` is used for debug output, right?

If I'm not mistaken, why do we see this result, with one showing the list on a single line, and one showing the list on multiple lines?

```rust
fn main() {
    let x: Vec<u32> = (0..10).collect();
    println!("{:?}", x[0..1].to_vec());
    dbg!(x[0..1].to_vec());
}
```

```
[src/main.rs:4] x[0..1].to_vec() = [
    0,
]
[0]
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e52aa2408885d5fc9ea970c4a145962a)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`dbg!` does not use `{:?}` but `{:#?}`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1a563362865e6051d4c350544131228e8eff5138/src/libstd/macros.rs#L347).

The [extra `#`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html#sign0) means that `dbg!` will use the alternate formatting, which uses more spaces and newlines, while the regular formatting is more dense.